# How to use a default image icon for a UIButton instead of a UIBarButton item

Tags: c#, xcode, xamarin

As seen by the screen shots below. I am using a UIBarButton item to use a search icon as an image:

[image]

The image below shows that I am using a toolbar to use the image button.

[image]

This is how the bar button item is identified as a search icon.

[image]

**The problem**: How do I do the same thing for a UIButton?

I've tried doing this programmatically or through the interface builder but cannot find anyway to do do the same thing. I know I can use a background image for the UIButton, but I want to simply choose the identifier like a UIBarButton. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `UIButton` has a very limited list of default icons, unlike the `UIBarButtonItem`. The search icon is not one of them. These are available as enum values of [UIButtonType](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIButtonType):

- UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure
- UIButtonTypeInfoLight
- UIButtonTypeInfoDark
- UIButtonTypeContactAdd

Comment: Do you know why Apple didn't include this setting for UIButton?

Comment: That's a very good question. I don't know, but they might have had the idea that such actions are better off in a toolbar (where they are logically grouped) rather than scattered over the whole screen.